# Cannot delete files on linux server from Go app using rm command

Tags: go

I have issue with deleting files on linux server

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
...
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 8 (Core)"
...
```

I have there default Go server on some port which do its job, generate some files, etc. And I need to remove old files. When I start server all works fine some time, but then, maybe in 1 day or less it stop deleting files.

I delete files using OS command RM

```
for _, info := range fileInfo {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    nm := filepath.Join(dir, info.Name())
    go func(name string, tm time.Duration) {
        debugf("del [%.2f]: %s", tm.Hours(), name)
        cmd, err := cmdPrepare.DeleteFile(name)
        if err != nil {
            debugf("P.DEL ERROR: %s\n%v\n", cmd.Args, err)
            return
        }
        if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
            debugf("R.DEL ERROR: %s\n%v\n", cmd.Args, err)
        }
    }(nm, diff)
}
...
...
...
// package cmdPrepare
...
func DeleteFile(pth string) (*exec.Cmd, error) {
    if pth == "" {
        return nil, errors.New("path is empty")
    }
    
    cmd := exec.Command("rm", "-frv", pth)
    
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout // set output in console
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    return cmd, nil
}
```

log output:

```
2020/11/20 02:45:01 --> xiaose: del [6.42]: /usr/local/bin/xiaose/bc4e13e14abd53d2b8d65a221eb21407.mp3
2020/11/20 02:45:01 --> xiaose: del [5.87]: /usr/local/bin/xiaose/1b64e1fdc463049ca35ec33b2a137fda.wav
2020/11/20 02:45:01 --> xiaose: R.DEL ERROR: [rm -frv /usr/local/bin/xiaose/1b64e1fdc463049ca35ec33b2a137fda.wav]
exit status 1
2020/11/20 02:45:01 --> xiaose: R.DEL ERROR: [rm -frv /usr/local/bin/xiaose/bc4e13e14abd53d2b8d65a221eb21407.mp3]
exit status 1
```

And files are there.

After that, when I restart server, on first round server app delete files as it should, and day after I have the same issue again.

PS. in prev. version of this app I used Go funcs os.RemoveAll(pth) and os.Remove(pth) but there also was issues with deleting folders and all files in folder, so I just replace it with OS func RM.

Comment: Does your process have the necessary permissions to delete the files?

Comment: Please don't tag this with "linux", see the description of that tag. That said, there are built-in facilities for file handling, no need to start an additional process that deletes files. That way, you could also get much better diagnostics I guess. Finally, it would help if you could provide a [mcve] so people don't have to guess how the files are created or deleted.

Comment: Sure, process has all permissions. I check it first

Answer (score -1):

Most likely this will be due to file permissions. And you rather use the [remove function from the os package](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Remove). You can return the error from the delete function and check against it inside the main or the caller (propagate the error and panic later). So why not simply do this:

```
func DeleteFile(filePath string) error {
    if filePath == "" {
        return errors.New("path is empty")
    }
    
    return os.Remove(filePath) // check against this error by the caller
}
```